# When is $f=\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)x^5-3x+\ln5$ decreasing $\forall\; x$?

Tags: calculus

When is $$f=\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)x^5-3x+\ln5$$ decreasing $\forall\; x$?

---

Diffrentiating:
$$f'=5\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)x^4-3$$
If $f$ is decreasing, $f'<0$:
$$5\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)x^4-3<0\implies x^4<\frac3{5\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)}$$
Since if $\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)\to0^+\implies x^4<+\infty$, which holds forallx, So:$$p=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{21}}2$$which doesn't ply with textbook-answer, since it mentions an domain for p.

Comment: You can't perform the division in the second step without accommodating the sign of the divisor. If the term you're dividing by is negative, it flips the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order the function be always decreasing, the requirement is that $$f'=5\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1\right)x^4-3$$ be negative for any value of $x$. Since $x^4 \geq 0$, then $$\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1 \lt 0$$ which implies either $p \gt 1$ or $-4 \lt p \lt \frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{21}\right)$

Comment: No, $\frac{\sqrt{p+4}}{1-p}-1 \le 0$ not $<$ and the answer is $p>1$ or $-4\le p\le \frac{1}{2}(3-\sqrt{21})$.